# Creating charging particles using Shuriken

Tags: unity, shuriken

I've been trying to create a charging effect using the Shuriken Particle system for the longest time, and I've had little to no luck with it. I've tried setting different curves for the Force over Time and Color over Time, but I always come up empty. However, I've seen examples all over the place for charging particles. The most recent example of charging particles I've seen is from the Space Cowboy game jam entry LOS CUERVOS.

The game has a ship with a laser that requires the player to hold a button down before it fires. It looks like this when charging and firing. I'm specifically talking about the particles surrounding the ball of light that's slowly growing in size over time.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone here knew what I may be doing wrong when going about setting up the particle system. Any suggestions relative to the question would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few properties for that:

- **Shape**

  - Shape = Sphere
  - Emit from Shell = true
  - Radius = Whatever works for you
- **Particle System**

  - Start speed = -40
- **Size over Lifetime**

  - Curve = Something small to large

Note that the speed is negative. This will cause the particles emitted from the shell of the sphere to move inwards toward the center.

One thing you'll have to tweak here is making sure that the lifetime and speed of the particles and the size of sphere balances to make the particles end their life just at the center of the sphere.

A few minutes of tweaking resulted in this for me:

[image]

Comment: I actually got it to work using this method. Thanks for the quick help. Any tips for getting particle systems to do different things (like tornadoes or spirals) other than just messing around with them for hours on end?

Comment: I haven't tried tornadoes or spirals, but I imagine you can move the emitter while setting the particles to simulate in world space, not local. I'm sure you can tweak it 'till you got something you liked.